# JavaScript library to allow user collaboration or TogetherJS alternatives

Tags: web-apps, javascript, collaboration, trello

I'm making a Trello clone, i.e a project management web app, and would like to add collaboration functionality so that a user can invite another user and they can work on the same "board"(as they do on Trello). I'm looking for a JavaScript library that enables collaboration to users via invite.

What are some or TogetherJS alternatives or a JavaScript library to allow user collaboration?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally familiar with TogetherJS, but see it uses web sockets for communication between clients. You can use [Socket.IO](https://socket.io/) to manage your own web socket connections. The invite will likely be a database operation, so users can get them while not on the application. Once a user opens a shared document/workspace, you can add their socket to a room and relay everything they do to all the other sockets in the room.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tried either of them, but am on a similar search.

You should check out Operation Transformation (see also  https://operational-transformation.github.io/ ) which gives an idea as to the complexities involved in implementing a library you might choose to use.

There is a nice writeup here [https://geovation.github.io/canvas-shared-editor#:~:text=requiring%20additional%20effort](https://geovation.github.io/canvas-shared-editor#:%7E:text=requiring%20additional%20effort)).-,ShareDB,persistent%20database%20with%20no%20queries.

Check out both the recommenations -  Firepad (tied into google services, may not be to all tastes) and ShareDB (appears to work a bit like TogetherJS, uses MIT license)

The latter is json document-centric, which might not suit all use cases.

You may also want to look at https://github.com/yjs